# Update dictionary and append if key exists

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I've got a list of dictionarys.

```
list_of_dicts = [{ a: 1, b:f, c:3}, {a: y, b:q, c:z, d: 1}, ... ]
```

Now i want to create a new dictionary which looks like:

```
newDict = { a: [1,y], b: [f,q], c: [3,z], d:[1]}
```

I know i could could make a double for loop, but that is rather slow since I'm dealing with large objects (mostly NumPy arrays) in the dictionaries.

```
newDict = {}
for l in list_of_dicts: 
    for k, v in l.items():
        if k in newDict: 
           newDict.append(v)
        else:
           newDict[k] = [v]
```

How to do this faster?

Comment: Please make sure your code is as correct as possible when you post. `list_of_dicts = [{ a: 1, b:f, c:3}, {a: y, b:q, c:z, d: 1}]` is invalid Python unless you tell us that `a`, `b`, `f`, `c` etc are variables.

Comment: f, y, q, z are large numpy arrays

Comment: That's beside the point. This is a simple question, so it's not critical, but a good habit to have. Answerers will be much more willing to help if they can just copy-paste your code to play with it. With non-functional code like yours, we either have to not use a computer and reason purely intellectually, or we have to spend time to construct example data ourselves that will allow us to run your code. If your question was more complex, I might've skipped it. You can replace the large array with e.g. `7`, or `"a"` if not relevant; but putting `a`there  drops your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a `collections.defaultdict()` will improve the performance:

```
result = defaultdict(list)
for d in list_of_dicts:
    for k, v in d.items():
        result[k].append(v)
```

Comment: Thank you, can you give the example for your second proposal?

Comment: @maniac I think that's just unnecessary here. The `defaultdict` approach is the best way to go at this situation. Unless you can create your list of dictionaries in another way before saving them in one list. Like using the `defaultfict` instead of list from beginning if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastest you can do this. You can replace the `if` with `newdict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)` to simplify it, but there is nothing you can do that will be faster than two loops.